# Is there a way to precache Lottie animations in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, lottie

I have a lottie animation that I'm using as a loading screen:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';

class Loading extends StatelessWidget {
  final String loadingText;
  Loading({this.loadingText});

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          if (loadingText != null) _buildLoadingText(loadingText),
          _buildAnimation(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildLoadingText(String text) {
    return Text(
      loadingText,
      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
          textStyle:
              TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.black)),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildAnimation() {
    return Lottie.asset('assets/lottie/heartbeat_loading.json',
        width: 300, repeat: true, animate: true);
  }
}
```

And I'm using it like this for when my app initially loads:

```dart
_determineHome() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: AppBlocContainer().authenticationBloc().loggedIn,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<AuthenticationStatus> snapshot) {
        // return Loading();
        return AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
            child: !snapshot.hasData
                ? Loading(
                    loadingText: 'Loading...',
                  )
                : _buildSecondChild(snapshot.data));
      },
    );
```

This works, except that the lottie animation is being loaded maybe a second or two too late, which by the time the lottie asset loads, it's too late and the page has already transitioned.

I was wondering since I did was able to precache my SVG images in my `main()` by doing this:

```dart
    Future.wait([
      precachePicture(
        ExactAssetPicture(
            SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, 'assets/svg/login.svg'),
        null,
      ),
      precachePicture(
        ExactAssetPicture(
            SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, 'assets/svg/logo.svg'),
        null,
      ),
      precachePicture(
        ExactAssetPicture(
            SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, 'assets/svg/signup_panel_1.svg'),
        null,
      )
    ]);
```

Would I be able to do the same thing with lottie?

Answer (score 8):

what I found is that lottie package in flutter, itself got a built in auto cache.(want it or not it will cache the animation into ram)

method A(own made):
so you basically need to call Lottie.asset('assets/Logo.json') once and the second time you will be able to load it without delay by calling Lottie.asset('assets/Logo.json') again because it was cached at the first time.
so this can be used as a cheat cache method, for example you can load it first in splash screen like below:
either by wrapping with a SizedBox and giving 0 height/width or using Visibility widget with visible property of false but maintainState to true, so its not visible but still will be in widget tree and load into ram.

```
        Visibility(
          visible: false,
          maintainSize: false,
          maintainState: true,
          maintainAnimation: false,
          maintainInteractivity: false,
          child: Row(
            children: [
               Lottie.asset('assets/Logo.json'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

next time where you need just call Lottie.asset('assets/Logo.json') and it will load without delay.

method B:
this is mentioned by a guy called Pante on github.

```
class LottieCache {

  final Map<String, LottieComposition> _compositions = {};

  /// Caches the given [LottieAsset]s.

  Future<void> add(String assetName) async {
      _compositions[assetName] = await AssetLottie(assetName).load();
  }
  
  Widget load(String assetName, Widget fallback) {
    final composition = _compositions[assetName];
    return composition != null ? Lottie(composition: composition) : fallback;
  }

}
```

there are 2 ways here:
1)use AssetLottie(assetName).load() method; provide the LottieCache object in order to access its load method where ever you need.
2)completly neglect load method and the composition way(you can comment the load method);because  AssetLottie(assetName).load() loads the animation into ram just as the same as Lottie.asset('assets/Logo.json')
so just calling its add method will load animation into ram and you can use it without delay next time where you need.

method C:
this is a custom loading method mentioned in lottie documentation for flutter.

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  late final Future<LottieComposition> _composition;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _composition = _loadComposition();
  }

  Future<LottieComposition> _loadComposition() async {
    var assetData = await rootBundle.load('assets/LottieLogo1.json');
    return await LottieComposition.fromByteData(assetData);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<LottieComposition>(
      future: _composition,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        var composition = snapshot.data;
        if (composition != null) {
          return Lottie(composition: composition);
        } else {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Method 3rd is the best! even it is recommened by original team